# Getting Rid of rows in R based on if a specific column has a character in it

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

Using this sample dataframe in R:

```
1123 2 3 4
2789 1 3 5
C2124 1 44 6 
CS112 3 32 1
```

This data frame is huge, but this is all the info that's really needed to solve the problem I believe. How do I delete all rows in my dataframe where the first column (lets call it x and the dataframe df) starts with C or CS? I think my data frame is in a list format and not actually vectorized, because gsub doesn't work.

Comment: Apologies, I needed it in all my other questions and habit caused me to put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `grep` to match elements that have only numbers including `.` from start (`^`) to end (`$`) and subset the rows based on this logical `vector`

```
 df[grepl("^[0-9.]+$", df[,1]), ]
```

Or simply convert to `numeric` and the non numeric elements will be NA (with a friendly warning and remove those rows by converting to logical vector with `is.na`

```
df[!is.na(as.numeric(df[,1])),]
```

For specific cases of strings that start with 'C' or 'CS', match it using regex (`"^CS*`)  which implies a string that starts with 'C' followed by 0 or more 'S' and negate (`!`) the logical `vector` to subset the rows

```
df[!grepl("^CS*", df[,1]),]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```
df %>% filter(!str_detect(x, "^C"))
```

or use `grepl`:

```
df %>% filter(!grepl("^C", x))
```